# Have a custom primary key for users.id in flask-security

Tags: flask, flask-login, flask-security, flask-principal

I want to have a custom key for the field id, for example, id_user, I've tried the following

```
class UserModel(db.model, UserMixin)
...
        @property
        def id(self):
            return self.id_user
```

But couldn't make it work. When I try to login it sends me this message:

```
{
"message": "You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server."
}
```

Comment: Need more info - what version of flask-security and flask are you using. That error message I don't think comes from Flask-Security - if login fails - assuming you are using forms - you should get a form back (from POST /login).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a nasty solution. I cloned the UserModel object, added a duplicated field for id, with the custom key I needed and told Flask-Security to use that object as the UserModel This is the function code I used:

```
def clone_model(model):
data = model
attr = getattr(model, "id_user")
setattr(data, "id", attr)
return data

cUserModel = clone_model(UserModel)
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, cUserModel, Roles)

security = Security(app, user_datastore)
```

Hope someone find it useful

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who is using [Flask-Security-Too](https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) looking to change the default id column, here is my solution.

##### Define the User and Role Tables as usual and just define the id column depending on your preference.

```
class Role(db.Model, FsRoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'role'

    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)


class Users(db.Model, FsUserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
```

For me, I need to use `String` primary_key Column. For that to I needed to change the many-to-many relationship table *`(roles_users)`*. Below is the code snippet for the same.

```
# Initialize the db object
db = SQLAlchemy()


# import this Class
from flask_security.models.fsqla_v2 import FsModels

# call this after creating the db object
FsModels.db = db
FsModels.user_table_name = 'users' # If you want a different table name than the default
FsModels.role_table_name = 'role'

# Create the relationship table as per your preferences
FsModels.roles_users = db.Table(
    "roles_users",
    Column("user_id", String, ForeignKey("users.id")),
    Column("role_id", String, ForeignKey("role.id")),
)
```